# What do you call a hustler in Russian?

Tags: перевод

A hustler is a person, who does something useful and talks a lot about it, as shown below.

[image: Charlatan, Martyr and Hustler]

What is a good expression for that in Russian?

I'm interested only in those expressions, which regard hustling as something positive.

Comment: Is it a synonym to enthusiast?

Comment: @Anixx I'm not sure that in Russian you can use *enthusiast* for someone, who wants to build a business (like a hustler usually does). But that's a subjective thing.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly what are you looking for, but if we take Webster's definition of "hustler":

> an ambitious person who eagerly goes after what is desired

, the best Russian correspondence I believe would be *хват*:

> *ХВАТ, -а; м. Нар.-разг.* Бойкий, ловкий, удалой человек. Держаться, выглядеть хватом. Х. парень, детина, баба. Ай да хваты ребята!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best variant is the adjective *бойкий* which stands for both *determined* and *lively*. Quite often that implies that one likes talking too.

If only one noun is needed then it can be formed by prefix "*бой-*" as the following: *бой-парень* (guy), *бой-девка* (girl), *бой-баба* (woman).

Answer (score 2):

"увлеченный человек" - это, кажется, наиболее близкое

Comment: Может *энтузиаст*?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko "энтузиаст" это ближе к "человек работающий за идею, а не за деньги") учитывая современные реалии это слово приобретает долю ироничности) ну и еще мне кажется Quassnoi хорошо написал что хастлер это скорее хват. т.е. получается что в вопросе неправильно объясняется слово хастлер, а я не настолько силен в английском чтобы самому в этом разобраться.